# Ionic 2 - How to Get data with Header Token? - Can't resolve all parameters for Headers

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm new on Ionic2, I would really appreciate your help.
I need to get data from an login API, adding a token parameter in header. 
Here is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class AuthProvider {
data:any;
  constructor(public http: Http) {
  }
  load() {
    if (this.data) {
      // already loaded data
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      let headers = new Headers();
     headers.append('token', '**HERE THE TOKEN**');

      this.http.get('**HERE THE API URL**', {"headers": headers})
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {

          this.data = data;
          resolve(this.data);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

When im run Ionic Serve, im getting a message:
**Can't resolve all parameters for Headers: (?).**

I have tried in Postman and the data is fetched correctly.
What can i do ?

I would really apreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Any indication of error line?

Comment: This the full errror:
    at syntaxError (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:78770:34)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:92107:35)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:91975:26)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:91961:21)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:92251:40)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:92180:49

Comment: at Array.forEach (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:92141:19)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:91796:50)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:102860:66)

Answer (score 0):

As ,I go through the tutorials there I found that for using the header first you have to set the header value after that you may use the append for header. like

```
 let headers = new Headers();
     headers.set('token', '**HERE THE TOKEN**');
```

and you may also check [Add header to API link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/add-header-to-a-api-call/55814) here.

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of try, i make it work.
In the class, i declare the API url:

```
export class TestPage {

  public urlBase = "https://apiurl.com"}
  public datos:any;

  connect(): Observable<Response> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'token': 'TOKENHERE' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http
      .get(`${this.urlBase}`, options)
  }
```

then i create a function to map data to JSON

```
  showdata(){

    this.leerDatos().map(res => {
   this.data= res.json();
}
).subscribe(

  (data) => {
    console.log('Connection OK!:', this.data);
  }
```